# How Do I Bind A HTML Input To A Function In React?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following in my React component

```
export default function BookAdderComponent(props) {
  const booksPresenter = new BooksRepository();

  return (
    <>
     <h5>Add Book</h5>
      name : <input></input><br/>
      title : &nbsp;&nbsp; <input></input><br/>
      <button onClick={() => {
            booksRepo.addBook({
              id: 131,
              name: "My Book",   //.1 how do I bind to name input?
              ownerId: "a@b.co",
              author: "tom hurst" //.2 how do I bind to title input?
            })
          }}>
          add book
        </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

How do I 2-way-bind my two html input values to things I am going to send in my repository function later on?

I'm looking for the simplest easiest way I need to demo this to someone.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want/need but you could create a state to hold the input values and then populate it using `onChange`. From there you can reference your state in `addBook` e.g `name : this.state.name`

Answer (score 2):

In the example below I have added `name` and `title` of book to state and passed that data down to `booksRepo` `addBook` method on button click titled `Add Book`

Below is the working code:

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import booksRepo from "./booksRepo";


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    title: ""
  };
  handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    booksRepo.addBook(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h5>Add Book</h5>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={e => {
            this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.title}
          onChange={e => {
            this.setState({ title: e.target.value });
          }}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add Book</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**booksRepo.js**

```
const addBook = ({ name, title }) => {
  console.log("the name of books is ", name);
  console.log("the title of books is ", title);
};

const booksRepo = {
  addBook: addBook
};

export default booksRepo;
```

Hope that helps!!!